# ChromeOS: How to go to last (or nth last) window?

Tags: chromebook, google-chrome-os

When I click the Chrome Icon, I can see a sorted list (creation time) of Chrome Windows.

What's an easy way to Alt-Tab to the chosen window (eg the last one)?

(The order shown when I hit Alt-Tab is of "last use" order and I can't tell which is which when there are many windows.)

Comment: Doesn't it work the Windows way? Alt-Tab, keep holding Alt, then also hold shift and press tab again to cycle the other direction? so Alt-Tab, Alt-shift-tab, alt-shift-tab?

Comment: @LPChip, yea that gives the "last use" order.

Answer (score 0):

You could do it the windows way.

Hold <kbd>alt</kbd> then press <kbd>tab</kbd> once to trigger the dialog once, then hold <kbd>shift</kbd> and press <kbd>tab</kbd> twice. Press <kbd>tab</kbd> more times to continue selecting newer apps.

But if you just want to switch to the last program, pressing <kbd>alt</kbd>-<kbd>shift</kbd>-<kbd>tab</kbd> once is probably just as easy.

Comment: It moves through the list by last focused time, not window creation time.

Comment: Oh, I'm sorry. I misunderstood your question. I don't know how it works for window creation time. Not even sure if that is possible.